# POWER BI - Maximum value with if condition

Tags: if-statement, filter, max, powerbi

I'm trying to calculate the maximum value with multiple conditions in Power BI.

The dataframe is:

```
Year    Company         Bond            Branch      Group     Type    Value
2016    BANCO DO BRASIL INDEPENDENTE    RISK        RETAIL    NOMINAL 4061567
2016    BANCO DO BRASIL INDEPENDENTE    ACUMULAÇÃO  RETAIL    NOMINAL 1901920
2017    BANCO DO BRASIL INDEPENDENTE    RISK        CORPORATE REAL    439499
2017    BANCO DO BRASIL INDEPENDENTE    RISK        RETAIL    REAL    356231
2016    BRADESCO        INDEPENDENTE    RISK        CORPORATE NOMINAL 347369
2016    BANCO DO BRASIL INDEPENDENTE    ACUMULAÇÃO  RETAIL    REAL    310920
2016    BANCO DO BRASIL LIGADO A BANCO  RISK        CORPORATE NOMINAL 12091
2016    BANCO DO BRASIL INDEPENDENTE    ACUMULAÇÃO  RETAIL    REAL    1021
2017    BANCO DO BRASIL INDEPENDENTE    RISK        CORPORATE REAL    446
```

I want to create a column with the maximum value by year, Bond, Branch, Group and Type disconsidering Company.

I've already tried the following code:

```
MAX = CALCULATE(MAX(data[Value]);
      FILTER(ALLEXCEPT(data;data[Company];
      data[Year] = data[Year] 
      && data[Branch] = data_segmento_anual[Branch]
      && data_segmento_anual[Group] = data_segmento_anual[Group]
      && data_segmento_anual[Bond] = data_segmento_anual[Bond]
      && data_segmento_anual[Type] = data_segmento_anual[Type]))
```

I'm expecting this result:

```
Year    Company             Bond            Branch      Group     Type    Value   MAX 
    2016    BANCO DO BRASIL INDEPENDENTE    RISK        RETAIL    NOMINAL 4061567 4061567
    2016    BANCO DO BRASIL INDEPENDENTE    ACUMULAÇÃO  RETAIL    NOMINAL 1901920 1901920 
    2017    BANCO DO BRASIL INDEPENDENTE    RISK        CORPORATE REAL    439499  439499
    2017    BANCO DO BRASIL INDEPENDENTE    RISK        RETAIL    REAL    356231  356231
    2016    BRADESCO        INDEPENDENTE    RISK        CORPORATE NOMINAL 347369  347369
    2016    BANCO DO BRASIL INDEPENDENTE    ACUMULAÇÃO  RETAIL    REAL    310920  310920
    2016    BANCO DO BRASIL LIGADO A BANCO  RISK        CORPORATE NOMINAL 12091   12091
    2016    BANCO DO BRASIL INDEPENDENTE    ACUMULAÇÃO  RETAIL    REAL    1021    310920
    2017    BANCO DO BRASIL INDEPENDENTE    RISK        CORPORATE REAL    446     439499
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `ALLEXCEPT` is removing all context *except* for `Company`, which is the opposite of what you want. Put what you want to *keep* inside `ALLEXCEPT`.

```
CALCULATE (
    MAX ( data[Value] );
    ALLEXCEPT (
        data;
        data[year];
        data[Branch];
        data_segmento_anual[Bond];
        data_segmento_anual[Group];
        data_segmento_anual[Type]
    )
)
```

The other way to do it is to use `ALL` to specify the column that you want to be ignored.

```
CALCULATE ( MAX ( data[Value] ); ALL ( data[Company] ) )
```

This can potentially cause problems though if other columns get added that you also want to ignore but you forget to put inside the `ALL`.

Comment: Do you know how could I get the second, third, fifith ... greater value and so on ?

Comment: You'd probably use `RANKX()` for that.